# A fatal esptool.py error occurred: Cannot configure port. PermissionError(13, 'A device attached to the system is not functioning.', None, 31)

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266, permissionerror, esptool

I am using a windows OS and I tried running a .ino code in arduino IDE for ESP8266 and came across the following error while trying to upload the code to ESP8266.

> A fatal esptool.py error occurred: Cannot configure port, something went wrong. Original message: PermissionError(13, 'A device attached to the system is not functioning.', None, 31)

I got to know that this error is being encountered by many people right now. I've used arduino IDE with esp8266 for some time now and this is the first time such an error has popped up. And I think it has something to do with the libraries or drivers installed while setting up the arduino IDE for ESP8266.

- Tried disconnecting the ESP8266 from my laptop and reconnecting it to a different USB port.
- Tried resetting the esp8266 using the RESET button to check if it was because of the hardware.
- Tried running the Arduino IDE as an administrator.

Comment: The error message is quite clear that you do not have permission to access the serial port.  How to get permission to access a serial port on your development machine is a question about system administration.  It is not a question about software development (even though the reason you want to use the serial port is for software development).  This means the question is not suitable for stack overflow.  This exact question has already been moved to superuser.stackexchange.com in the last 24 hours.  Asking the same thing again will not make it an allowed question!

Comment: Here is the migrated question:
https://superuser.com/questions/1781851/esptool-py-permissionerror-while-configuring-serial-port

Answer (score 18):

I encountered a similar issue and was able to resolve it by installing the [CH340_driver](https://sparks.gogo.co.nz/ch340.html). The CH340 driver provides essential support for devices utilizing the CH340 chipset, ensuring proper communication with your computer.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much, this saved me from throwing out my board

Comment: This driver also worked for VSCode with Espressif extension (non-Arduino). Same error as OP.

Comment: Note: the driver linked above is a version '3.4.2014.8' of CH340 driver instead of the most up-do-date version

Answer (score 6):

uninstall ch340 driver and freshly install the driver then you are good to go!!

Comment: how can i do that ... how can i uninstall and then install

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I uninstall CH430 driver( CH341SER.ZIP) and installed old version driver(Windows-CH340-Driver.ZIP 2016/11/30) and saved this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Need to setup on properties of port in manager devices speed of port, in my case was in cketch 115200 but in parameters of port 9600

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

i installed the driver https://sparks.gogo.co.nz/ch340.html  and it is working in single go just donwload the file unzip and install the driver it will directly run

Comment: This a permission problem, not a driver problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it seems like it's specific to Win11. The [Arduino online editor](https://create.arduino.cc/editor) should be a workaround for this though.

Answer (score 0):

installed again the ch34xx driver and it worked for windows 11

Answer (score 0):

Seems that windows 11 has some problems with the ch34xx driver, I had to reinstall it every time i reboot windows 11.
after reinstall it works perfectly ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to program AI Thinker ESP32-CAM board using ESP32 CAM BM programmer. I got this error.

"A fatal esptool.py error occurred: Cannot configure port, something went wrong. Original message: PermissionError(13, 'A device attached to the system is not functioning.', None, 31)".

I tried reinstalling the CH341 driver and it worked. But sometimes, I had to disconnect the ESP32 CAM BM programmer and close the arduino IDE completely, then reopen the IDE and reconnect the board to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

resolve the same issue with esp8266 Wemos based on ch340.
Just re-install [driver](https://sparks.gogo.co.nz/ch340.html)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I tried on WIn7 Pro and Win 10 OS.
Have the same problem.
After connecting my USB cable all working fine but everytime I got error during uploading a program like Com port access is denied.
My PC have 4 USB connectors and I got the numbers:6,7,8,9.
But always I got the same error like Com port access is denied.
I found the solution in change the COM port number, I put the number greater than 10->11.
After that Arduino working like charm!
Here is the solution:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BUKe0LfNxnw